# Assigning a a derived object to a baseclass pointer inside a function

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, object-slicing

I have a base class,

```
  struct MsgFormat {
    MsgFormat();
    virtual ~MsgFormat();

    const std::string rootNode;
  };
```

and a derived class,

```
 class ServiceMsg : public MsgFormat {
  public:    
    explicit ServiceMsg(std::string A, std::string B);
    ServiceMsg();
    ServiceMsg(const ServiceMsg& srvMsg);
    class ServiceMsg& operator=(const ServiceMsg& srvMsg);
    ~ServiceMsg();

    std::string A() const;
    std::string B() const;

  private:
    std::string m_A;
    std::string m_B;
};
```

Now I have a message handler class, that takes a pointer to the base class, like this,

```
  class MsgHandler
  {
  public:
    MsgHandler();
    virtual ~MsgHandler();

    virtual int parseIncoming(struct MsgFormat* pBaseMsg) = 0;
    virtual int formatOutgoing(const struct HermesMsgFormat* const pBaseMsg) = 0;
  };
```

};

Now, if I do something like this in the main(),

```
ServiceMsg* pSrvMsg = new ServiceMsg("foo", "bar");    
SpecificMsgHandler m_handle->formatOutgoing(pSrvMsg);
```

and inside the overloaded *formatOutgoing* method, I have something like this,

```
virtual int CustomMsgHandler::formatOutgoing(const struct MsgFormat* const pBaseMsg)
{
    const ServiceMsg* const pServiceMsg = dynamic_cast<const ServiceMsg* const>(pBaseMsg);
    std::cout << pServiceMsg->A() << std::endl;
    std::cout << pServiceMsg->B() << std::endl;
}
```

where *CustomMsgHandler* was inherited from the *MsgHandler* class, all is fine and good. And that is I guess the whole idea of polymorphism. You can pass objects of a derived class to an interface that accepts a pointer to the base-class.

---

What does not work is, the opposite. Where *parseIncoming()* does the following,

```
    virtual int CustomMsgHandler::parseIncoming(struct MsgFormat* pBaseMsg)
    {
       pBaseMsg = new ServiceMsg("bla", "baa");

#ifdef NDEBUG
       ServiceMsg* pServiceMsg = dynamic_cast<ServiceMsg*>(pBaseMsg);
        std::cout << pServiceMsg->A() << std::endl;
        std::cout << pServiceMsg->B() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "all good here" << std::endl;
#endif
    }
```

I do the following in the main().

```
MsgFormat* pBaseMsg = new pBaseMsg();
SpecificMsgHandler m_handle->parseIncoming(pBaseMsg);
```

But if I try to read from pBaseMsg in the main(), after returning from the call to *parseIncoming* message, I don't get the "bla" and "baa". I get what was set in the default constructor.

```
ServiceMsg* pServiceMsg = dynamic_cast<ServiceMsg*>(pBaseMsg);
std::cout << pServiceMsg->A() << std::endl;
std::cout << pServiceMsg->B() << std::endl;
std::cout << "all good here" << std::endl;
```

I don't understand why this 2nd case does not work. Or how best to make it work?

Comment: Assigning to a (non-reference) parameter has no effect outside the function.

Comment: Is the purpose of `parseIncoming()` method is to create a message? Judging by their names it seems that your methods should do just the opposite. Please clarify  which one of your methods, if any, is supposed to create a message.

Comment: @molbdnilo, I am passing a pointer. And I am assigning a new object to that pointer inside the function. How is that "practically" different from passing a variable by reference?

Comment: @r3musn0x, The function-names are irrelevant and only reflect the module that I am trying to write. The only real difference between parseIncoming() and formatOutgoing() is that, one accepts an object of a derived-class that was already created outside the method. The 2nd function, on the other hand, creates an object of the derived class inside the method, and tries to assign it to the base-class pointer - i.e. the base-class pointer that is a parameter of the function. I was expecting that once this function returns, the base-class pointer would have the object assigned to it in the method.

Comment: @molbdnilo, unless you mean, I should pass the pointer by reference. Ouch. I had a gut feeling of testing with pointer-to-pointer. But that felt too C for me. (Yes I do have more history with C than maybe C++.)

Comment: There's nothing special about pointers. If you want to modify a variable, you need to pass a pointer (or reference) *to that variable*, regardless of whether that variable is a pointer or not.

Comment: Understood. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the pointer by value. The function will make a copy of the pointer you pass in, you then modify the copy. That's why the changes are not visible in `main` after the function call.

To fix this you can pass the pointer by reference instead, by changing the signature of the function.

```
virtual int CustomMsgHandler::parseIncoming(struct MsgFormat*& pBaseMsg) //added &, it's now a reference to a pointer.
```

Also note that you are first doing a dynamic allocation in `main`.

```
MsgFormat* pBaseMsg = new pBaseMsg();
```

Then you pass this pointer to the function and again do a dynamic allocation.

```
pBaseMsg = new ServiceMsg("bla", "baa");
```

Here you forgot to `delete` the pointer first, so you leaked memory. Every call to `new` needs to have a call to `delete` to free the memory. (Unless it's passed to something like the constructor of a smart-pointer, then the smart-pointer will take care of `delete`ing for you.)

**When using c++11 or the boost equivalents**
There is really no need to use bare `new` and `delete` in modern C++. You should instead use things like `std::vector`, `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try the "passing-the-pointer-by-reference" solution that you mentioned and will get back to you. I had a feeling, I had to do that or use a pointer-to-pointer.

Comment: Regarding the memory leak, I do delete the pointer later in the code. This was just a chopped&cut down version of the real thing, showing only the part where I had the question/doubt. But thanks for mentioning it anyways.

Regarding, smart pointers and modern C++, who said, I was using modern C++? :P I am bound to the compiler used in the project. It is not my choice. There is no std::unique_ptr and no std::shared_ptr at hand. If you would say, use Boost then, then the answer is, I don't make that decision. The tools and libraries are fixed. I have neither C++11/newer nor Boost.

Comment: @JoeyMallone Just to clarify your question in the comment above, how is it pratically different to pass a pointer and a reference to a variable. When you pass a pointer, the object that the pointer points to can be modified and that change will reflect outside the function. In your example you are not doing that though. You are modifying the pointer itself, not the object the pointer points to.

Comment: @JoeyMallone I see. In that case this is indeed the way to do it, unless you want to write your own smart-pointer wrapper. It's still good to point it out in the answer for future readers. I'll clarify by adding a note above `c++11` required for that option.

Comment: Alles klar! Kommissar! ;) Thanks!